# JQuery jump page to top and bottom on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins

I'm using Laravel and I'm using jQuery to show some products.

I have a brand list using

and I will show some product by clicking on a brand. The brand id will taken by jquery and then I will hide() all of brands and show() all of the products which have the same id.

The problem is this: just and just on mobile, when for first time I click on a brand, the page will jump to top and when I'm coming down, the page will jump to bottom and it will be OK for two and more times

and when i use the : Display:none
this problem will solve but i need fade effect

A part of code:

```
$('#brand-names li').on('click', function (){
   window.id = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#brand-names").hide();
   $('.'+id).fadeToggle();
   $("#back_btn").fadeToggle();
});
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I just Attached JqueryMobile.js cdn after the jquery and problem solved...